# Is there a way to call a function inside a contract from a function in another contract?

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson

I want to have two different contracts that have functions that should interact with each other. Is there a way to pass/return values through function call between contracts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contracts don't currently return any data. You should use callbacks for on-chain data transmission, or use an off-chain oracle.

On chain, you use the TRANSFER_TOKENS; instruction to send from contract a to contract b. Contract b would then send data back via another TRANSFER_TOKEN; call. You should update the storage of contract a to acknowledge that a call back is imminent.

Comment: That’s the theory. In practice, it’s almost impossible to write it, because of the type system. B has to know the type of A, so either you have to deploy both contracts, or you have to originate an intermediary contract C that knows A and has a type compatible with B. We will post a blog post on that soon.

Comment: Yeah, we're developing a framework to help with this.

Comment: At some point, Liquidity will have native support for that too.

Comment: @FLFOCP perhaps write this as a separate answer ?

Comment: The answer to the problems mentioned above are entrypoints, which are described in more detail in this blog post: https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/category/in-depth.html#multiple-entrypoints